# How to achieve Bing maps like InfoWindow in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bing-maps

I'm using Google Maps v3.

I really like the InfoWindows found in Bing, as opposed to Google.

Screenshots & functionality found here comparing the two:

http://www.axismaps.com/blog/2009/07/data-probing-and-info-window-design-on-web-based-maps/

**Question**: How can I replicate Bing like InfoWindows while using Google Maps v3?

---

**UPDATE**: To be more specific, what I like about Bing's InfoWindows include:
- The pointer dynamically changes sides from left/right/bottom/top, as opposed to Google limited to only have the InfoWindow pointer on the bottom
- Bing's InfoWindows use less space
- You can configure Bing's InfoWindows to pop up outside of the map bounders so that you don't have to autopan the map to display the marker's InfoWindow

Answer (score 2):

Check out [google-maps-utility-library-v3](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/). Specifically, look at [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.0/docs/examples.html). It allows you to style the infobox however you want, although you have to do the styling on your own. I don't think you'll be able to have the infobox display outside the map viewport, but you can turn off autopan.